# run alarm manager if hour is within an interval?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-calendar

I'm using an alarm manager like this :

```
// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

So my alarm runs at 8:30 every day, but let's suppose that the user's phone is off at 8:30, how can I make it so the alarm starts running whenever the user's phone is available and the hour is within an interval. Let's say the interval is [8h, 18h] so once the user's phone is on and the current time is within that interval the alarm should be triggered.

Also, how is it possible to stop the alarm at 18h (supposing that it started running before)

Comment: Set the alarm manager to notify every 10 minutes. Then check if you didn't sound the alarm today and if the time is between 8 and 18.

Comment: Or you can set a boot intent receiver, and when the phone goes on, check if the time is between 8 and 18 and that you didn't sound the alarm today, then sound it. Much lighter solution.